How to control the placement of newly created layers in QGIS layer tree
When I create a new layer in QGIS, such as performing a buffer operation on a point, the resulting layer is automatically placed at the top of the Layers Panel (Table of Contents). This behaviour requires me to manually drag the layer to my desired position each time, which can be quite annoying in workflows involving the creation of multiple layers.
I am wondering if there is a setting or a workaround within QGIS that allows for more control over where newly created layers are positioned in the Layer Tree. Specifically, I'm looking for a way to have new layers added directly above the layer that was used in the operation (e.g., the point layer that was buffered), instead of defaulting to the top of the list. In previous QGIS versions, this used to be the default behaviour.
In Options, I have checked out "Canvas & Legend" > "Behaviour used when adding new layers" > "Above currently selected layer"...but this applies only to existing layers being added to the project.
Does anyone know if such a setting exists? I'd rather not have to mess around with some random plugin / script.

I dont know if it helps you but if you select the layer in ToC before you perform an operation, it will be automatically added directly above the layer you selected in ToC.

@Nil that used to be the case indeed, however it seems in the latest version (3.36) they are placed at the top of the layer tree.
